# Try... Catch in async await not catching error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why the try...catch is not working for below sample code?

```
const http2 = require("http2")
const url = require("url")


function sendRequest() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var r = http2.request({
            "host": "www.google.com",
            "method": "GET",
            "path": "/"
        }, (resp) => {
            var data = []
            resp.on("data", (chunk) => {
                throw ("Error")
            })
            resp.on("end", () => {
                console.log("ended")
                resolve("finished")
            })
            resp.on("error", (e) => {
                console.log("error")
                reject(e)
            })
        })
        r.end()
    })
}

async function wrapper(){
    try {
        console.log("Sending request")
        await sendRequest()
        console.log("Finished sending Request")
    }catch(e){
        console.log("error!") // Supposed to see this
        console.log(e)
    }
    console.log("All finished") // Supposed to see this
}

wrapper()
```

Output is as follow:

```
Sending request

/Users/test-user/test.js:15
                throw ("Error")
                ^
Error

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It's not the await that's the problem here, it's your promise.. your throwing an error, instead of calling reject.

Comment: Why is `data` an error in the first place?

Answer (score 16):

You can `throw` inside a promise and catch the error with `catch` so long as the error is in the promise itself and not in different async callback.

For example, the `test()` works as expected, but `test2()` does not:

```js
function test(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        throw (new Error("error"))
    })
}

function test2(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            throw (new Error("error"))
        }, 100)

    })
}
async function go (){
    try {
        await test()
    } catch(err){
        console.log("caught error from test(): ", err.message)
    }

    try {
        await test2()
    } catch(err){
        console.log("caught error from test2(): ", err.message)
    }

}
go()
```

Both cases work fine with `reject()` instead of `throw()`

Answer (score 0):

Because `throw` is only converted to a promise rejection in an `async` function, the *synchronous* portion of the promise executor (the callback you pass `new Promise`), or the *synchronous* portion of a `then` or `catch` callback. You're doing it in a non-`async` callback, which isn't any of those places.

`throw ("Error");` should be `reject("Error");` (well, really it should be `reject(new Error("Error"));` — rejections are errors, so using `new Error` gives you the stack trace, etc.).

---

Side note: Normally, receiving the `data` event wouldn't be an error in any case...

Side note 2: The `()` in `throw ("Error");` do nothing. When throwing is an option, simply `throw "Error";` (or, again, `throw new Error("Error");`).

Comment: Having error on chunk, might not be totally weird.  Eg, if say downloading a file and you expected to receive a ZIP, you could check the magic code in the first few chunks, and then abort & reject promise.  Saves downloading something that's not what your after.

Comment: @Keith: Sure. But the code in question is unconditional.

Comment: I think the code in questions is not for real.. :)